# Is 'now' within a "start - end" string?

Tags: java, time, simpledateformat

I have timerange strings like the following example:

"10:00 AM - 8:00 PM"

I know we're always going to be dealing with EST.

I'm looking for a simple way of handling parsing this so that I can check if "now" is within the time range.

My initial thought is I need to do a string split on the "-", trim the strings, and then use simpledateformat to take "10:00 AM"  and "8:00 PM" into time objects. From there I would check if "now" is after 10am, and before 8pm.

My thought is there might be a simpler method in a java library to handle all of this and return a boolean true/false. Does anyone have suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"My thought is there might be a simpler method"* Simpler than what? You haven't shown any code to compare with. --- *Possible answers:* A) No, there is no simpler way than what you did. B) Yes, there is a simpler way than what you did. C) Since you haven't done anything, it's impossible to tell if there is a simpler way. --- Which of those 3 answers fit your question? We have no way of knowing.

Comment: @Andreas Reading the section before the one you quoted, I gave a rough algorithm for what I planned to do. I was asking if that made the most sense. I didn't write code yet, because I wanted to know if there was a better way of tackling it. In short, does what I wrote make the most sense, or would you approach it another way? I'm asking for suggestions on improving my way of handling this situation. If you don't have one, that's fine, at least I know I am on the right path!

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead split the string at the dash and use `LocalTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3):

There is no another easier way, try something like that:

```
  static boolean isInBetween(LocalTime timeToCheck, String bounds){
String[] timebounds = bounds.split("-", 0);
LocalTime now = timeToCheck;
LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse(timebounds[0].substring(0 , timebounds[0].length()-1), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a", Locale.US));
LocalTime end = LocalTime.parse(timebounds[1].substring(1), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a", Locale.US)) ;
    return now.isAfter(start) && now.isBefore(end);
}
```

do some checking to make sure the array is not empty and neither is the LocalTime you give.

Comment: 1) Code throws `DateTimeParseException: Text '10:00 AM ' could not be parsed` --- 2) Why is return type a *boxed* `Boolean`, not a regular `boolean`? --- 3) What if "now" is `timeToCheck` is exactly the start time? --- 4) Invalid Java syntax.

Comment: Hi Andreas, in fact there were several errors, sorry but I could not check at that moment if it worked or not, now I have modified the code and this version should work. In my main there is this.

        boolean itis= isInBetween(LocalTime.parse("10:00 AM", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a", Locale.US)), "10:00 AM - 12:00 PM");

Comment: 1) Wouldn't it be easier to do `split(" *- *")` or to use `trim()`, instead of those `substring()` calls? --- 2) Don't call `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern` twice. Do it once, assign to local variable, then use it twice. --- 3) *Repeat:* What if "now" in `timeToCheck` is exactly the start time? Normally, for a range like "10:00 AM - 8:00 PM", the start time of 10 AM would be considered in-range, this code does not.